# How to join table with maximum value in column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

This seems like a fairly simple SQL statement, but I'm just not seeing it. I have:

- a table called Groups. columns are Id, Name, Address, and a bunch of other columns we don't care about.
- a table called People. columns are Id, GroupId, Name, Priority, and a bunch of other columns we don't care about.

I want a list of all Groups. each row in this list needs to have the Id, Name, and Address of the Group. It also needs to have the Name of the person with the highest Priority. Priority can be NULL as well, which would be selected if there was no other person in that group with a non null. If there are any ties for Priority, I don't care which one gets selected as long as its one of them.

Sample data:

```
Group: (Id, Name, Address)
1, Group A, Address A
2, Group B, Address B
3, Group C, Address C
4, Group D, Address D
```

```
People: (Id, GroupId, Name, Priority)
1, 1, Alice, 39
2, 1, Bob, 22
3, 1, Craig, 88
4, 2, David, NULL
5, 2, Elise, 3
6, 3, Frank, NULL
```

Results should be:

```
1, Group A, Address A, Craig
2, Group B, Address B, Elise
3, Group C, Address C, Frank
4, Group D, Address D, NULL
```

I can use `SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY Priority DESC` to get the rows in the right order, but I'd need to only get the first row for each GroupId from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer will also work, but this is useful if you also want to, say, know both the person and the priority of that person (In my experience this kind of thing is common):

```
SELECT Id, Name, Address, Person, Priority
FROM 
(
    SELECT g.Id, g.Name, g.Address, p.Name Person, p.Priority,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY g.ID ORDER BY p.Priority DESC) rn
    FROM [Group] g
    INNER JOIN People p ON p.GroupID = g.ID
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to like `row_number()`. Gives me `Incorrect syntax near ')'`

Comment: @vkapadia I was missing a comma.

Comment: Still error. Now saying `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'g'.`

Comment: @vkapadia What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Testing using SQL Server 2019, but the eventual query is going to run on SQL Azure.

Comment: Oh, I was also missing an `=` :(

Answer (score 2):

Use a sub-query to obtain the relevant Person per group.

```
SELECT *
    , (
        SELECT TOP 1 Name
        FROM People p
        WHERE p.GroupId = g.Id
        ORDER BY Priority DESC
    )
FROM GROUP g;
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I also wanted to get more columns from the People table in the final set?

Comment: Thats not what you asked. So you'd need to ask a new question. You need to ensure your question covers the full scenario you wish to handle